# viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear Uses

Tags: ios, viewdidload, viewdidappear

As per my understanding, `viewDidLoad()` is called when the view is created and used for things that need to happen once whereas `viewWillAppear()` is used for tasks that require to repeat every time a VC comes on screen.

What is the difference in tasks doing them once and repeating whenever VC comes on a screen?

Currently, I have a `View` with a bunch of `UILabels` and `UITextFields`. Technically, I need to only create and set the text only once but each time you visit that `View` it will need to be done. Would that logic make sense more in a `viewWillAppear()` in comparison to a `viewDidLoad()`.

My reasoning to put them in `viewDidLoad()` was that they only need to happen once. Then again, you can argue that each time you're on that specific `View` it will need to happen each time. Unsure if my understanding is correct or not...or if I'm overthinking

Comment: Viewdidload getting called after the UIView is prepared in memory. If the view is not removed from the memory, it won’t get called.

Answer (score 0):

You miss a point that is whenever you create a new instance of the vc it's `viewDidLoad` is called once , that means if you dismiss that vc or pop it ( if it's inside a navigation controller ) then it completely deallocates ( if no strong references exists ) , that's a story with 1 instance , if you presented another instance it'll go the same , But

For the lifeTime of 1 instance `viewDidLoad` is called once , and `viewWillAppear`/`viewDidAppear` are called whenever you dismiss a vc that's presented by that instance or pop that child from the stack

Inject the setup code inside `viewDidLoad` , and any content that you want to refresh set it in `viewWillAppear`/`viewDidAppear` for ex suppose you have a table lists some items and you add the item in a modal vc , then you go place `tableView.reloadData()` in `viewWillAppear` , but for adding the tableView to the view , you make that inside `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat difficult to answer your question without having more information about what exactly it is you want to achieve, but it might be helpful to keep in mind this diagram about the view controller life cycle:

[image: View Controller Life Cycle]

If you place a UILabel or UITextField on a view in viewDidLoad, they will continue to be there every time viewWillAppear() is called, and thus you do not need to instantiate those labels or fields again in viewWillAppear().

Answer (score 0):

Here is how they could be used in a simple game workflow:

- instantiate a UILabel (a game score, for example) in ViewDidLoad of a main menu UIView
- load the main menu
- present a game scene, play game, etc...
- get a new high score, the main menus ViewDidAppear updates the UILabel with the new score, and when the game scene is dismissed the UILabel will reflect the new score.